# Detect if Room Destructive Migration is Performed

Tags: android, android-room

If I run a Room migration with destructive fallback enabled:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, MyDb::class.java, "database-name")
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .build()
```

Is there a way to determine if the destructive migration was triggered vs if the migration completed successfully? I'd like to be able to log some information for tracking.

Comment: `addCallback(myCallback)` should be called upon the new creation right?

Comment: Yes, it looks like `Callback` has an `onDestructiveMigration` callback method on it. If you write it up as a full answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use use Room [`Callback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Callback) and [add it to your database](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#addCallback(androidx.room.RoomDatabase.Callback)), it has below methods: where you can use `onDestructiveMigration`

- [**onCreate**:](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Callback#onCreate(androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase)) Called when the database is created for the first time
- [**onOpen**:](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Callback#onOpen(androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase)) triggered when you open the database
- [**onDestructiveMigration:**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Callback#onDestructiveMigration(androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase)) Called after the database was destructively migrated

Here is a sample example

Java:

```
@Database(entities = {...}, version = 1)

public abstract class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabaseName.db";

    private static volatile MyDatabase INSTANCE;

    public static MyDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (MyDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    // Create database here.
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                    MyDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .addCallback(mCallback) // Trigger the callback
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }


    /*
     * Callback when database is created & when it’s opened
     * */
    static RoomDatabase.Callback mCallback = new Callback() {


         /*
         * Callback when database is first-time created or recreated after destruction
         * */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) { // 
            super.onCreate(db);
            Log.i("LOG_TAG", "Database is created");
        }

        /*
         * callback when the database is opened
         * */
        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) { 
            super.onOpen(db);
            Log.i("LOG_TAG", "Database is opened");
        }

        /*
         * Called after the database was destructively migrated
         * */
        @Override
        public void onDestructiveMigration(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onDestructiveMigration(db);
            Log.i("LOG_TAG", "Database is destructed");
        }
    };

}
```

Kotlin:

```
@Database(entities = [...], version = 1)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    companion object {

        private const val DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabaseName.db"
        private var INSTANCE: MyDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): MyDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    MyDatabase::class.java,
                    DATABASE_NAME
                ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(mCallback) // Trigger the callback
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }

        /*
         * Callback when database is created & when it’s opened
         * */
        var mCallback: Callback = object : Callback() {
        
             /*
             * Callback when database is first-time created or recreated after destruction
             * */       
            override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onCreate(db)
                Log.i("LOG_TAG", "Database is created")
            }
            
            /*
             * callback when the database is opened
             * */
            override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {  
                super.onOpen(db)
                Log.i("LOG_TAG", "Database is opened")
            }

            /*
             * Called after the database was destructively migrated
             * */
            override fun onDestructiveMigration(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onDestructiveMigration(db)
                Log.i("LOG_TAG", "Database is destructed")
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}
```